# Ajax Jquery call made with WCF service

Tags: wcf, web-services, jquery, .net-4.5

I have found tons of articles and posts about making jquery ajax calls to WCF services. I cannot seem to find one good tutorial for doing this in .net 4.5. I have found an msdn blog post that claims to allow you to do it, but it does not work. Below is what it claims is all you need to change in your web.config and everything else can be left as the basic template code it comes with.

```
    <services>
  <service name="WcfServiceAjax.Service">

    <endpoint address="ajaxEndpoint" behaviorConfiguration="AjaxBehavior"
     binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="AjaxBinding" 
     contract="WcfServiceAjax.IService"></endpoint>

    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:62069"/>
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>

  </service>
```

When I try to invoke the service either directly using this

```
 http://localhost:62069/Service.svc/GetData
```

I just get a 404 error 
when I try invoking it with

```
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
 <script>

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "Service.svc/GetData",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (msg) {
        alert(msg.d);
    },
    error: function () {
        alert('eh, fack!');
    }
});
</script>
```

I get "Failed to load resource". I really am just looking for a single easy to follow tutorial on how to call a WCF service with jQuery ajax in .net 4.5. I understand there are a lot of posts like this one, but I have yet to find one targeting 4.5 directly.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think the 404 error is because your ajax call calls `Service.svc/GetData` 
whereas your service is made available at the endpoint address: `<endpoint address="ajaxEndpoint"`

Comment: I am using this to hit it now and I am still getting a 404 so I'm not sure if that is the case or maybe I am still using the wrong url http://localhost:62069/ajaxEndpoint/GetData

Comment: How are you hosting the service? Self hosted or IIS using an SVC-file?

Comment: its is hosted using iis express I will be using IIS to host it when all is said and done

Comment: Could you post your .svc-file?